# SPA Vue pod in AKS keeps restarting

Tags: docker, vue.js, kubernetes, nginx

I am deploying my frontend to AKS in a container image. I am using Nginx as a web server. Now I have written a Dockerfile which consists of two stages. The build stage and the production stage. The application gets build in the build stage using npm install and npm run build. Afterwards, I am copying the created dist folder to my production stage and putting it in a folder called /app. Then I am copying the nginx.conf file from my repo to the image and start the app.

This is the docker file:

```
# build stage
FROM node:18-alpine AS build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine AS production-stage
RUN apk update && apk upgrade -U -a
RUN mkdir /app
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /app
COPY infra/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Now building this goes as it should. When I deploy it to AKS the pod keeps restarting. The logs show the following:

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
```

They don't really show any error messages.

Does anyone know what I should change in my dockerfile to deploy the image to my AKS cluster?